# why .live not working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, jquery

I finished coding my jQuery site but I have found that .live jQuery is not supported with IE9 or in fact any IE.

Or at least that is my experience.

I am wondering how to get IE to do the following

```
$('ul#mainmenu a li').live('click', function(event){
        //alert(this.id);

        $("li#"+lastpageid).removeClass();
        fetchpage(this.id);


        var text = '';
        $('a li#'+this.id+'').contents().each(function(){
        if(this.nodeType === 3){
         text += this.wholeText;
        }
        });

        $("#largemenutop").html(text);

        $("li#"+this.id).addClass("active");
        lastpageid = this.id;
});
```

Comment: Why would you have the `<li>`'s inside of anchors? You're selectors don't make any sense. Does it work in any other browsers like Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: tylermwashburn  is correct you should really change you html to have the hyperlinks inside of the `<li>`s

Comment: If you open IE developer tools and goto the console and run `$('ul#mainmenu a li').length` does it return the number of elements you expect?

Comment: You should use `$(this)` instead of `$("li#"+this.id)`. However this won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have pointed out make sure your HTML structure makes sense i.e. put the anchor INSIDE the li `<li><a href="">blah</a></li>` not `<a href=""><li>blah</li></a>`

`<li>` is a structured list, doing the above has no structure meaning and isn't the right way to do things.

If your aim is to have the anchor take up the full with of the list item, then make the anchor a block element in CSS: `li a { display: block; }`

Anyway, you could try using `.delegate` in this situation. I've restructured your code, I'm assuming `fetchpage` works as expected.

```
var $lastAnchor = jQuery();

$('#mainmenu').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $lastAnchor.removeClass('active');

    fetchpage(this.id);

    $('#largemenutop').html(
        $this
          .addClass('active')
          .contents()
          .filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; })
          .text()
    );

    $lastAnchor = $this;
});
```

Ensure it's all inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`